# ¿Cómo ingresar datos por teclado en un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario llenado desde el código, pero necesito que en vez de estar lleno y solo mostrar el resultado, que el diccionario se vaya llenando en tiempo de ejecución, lo estoy usando para la implementación del algoritmo de Dijkstra.

```
vertices = {'a': {'b': 8, 'c': 5},
            'b': {'a': 8, 'c': 15, 'd': 10},
            'c': {'a': 5, 'b': 15, 'e': 13},
            'd': {'b': 10, 'c': 18, 'e': 12, 'f': 3},
            'e': {'c': 13, 'd': 12, 'f': 5},
            'f': {'d': 3, 'e': 5}}
```

He encontrado métodos como `setdefault()` pero la verdad no entiendo bien cómo funciona, o si puedo leer `key` y `value` con un `input` y solo llenar con el método `setdefault()`.

Lo que guarda el diccionario son las distancias entre un vértice principal y las distancias con los vértices, para así poder calcular la distancia mínima de un vértice inicio hacia un vértice final. Espero puedan ayudarme ; ).

Comment: Claro que si he investigado y mucho, pero la verdad es que soy nueva en Python, además ya tengo el resto del código listo y lo único que me faltaría es hacerle esa pequeña modoficación.

Comment: Podrias mostrar lo que hiciste, y cual es el problema particular que tenes para llenar esa matriz?

Comment: Para poder responder a la pregunta es necesario que definas mejor cómo sería la interacción con el usuario que te proporcione esos datos de distancias. ¿Te valdría que el usuario teclee toda esa estructura más o menos como se ve en Python? ¿O que te de un nombre de fichero y lo leas de ahí? ¿O tienes que hacer un bucle en el que se vaya iterando por cada pareja de nodos y se le pregunte al usuario la distancia? (tendría que introducir algún carácter especial para señalar parejas que no están conectadas?)

Comment: El problema de usar el diccionario es que no sé cómo llenarlo con valores dados por el usuario en tiempo de ejecución, no se si es como llenar un arreglo en c++.

Comment: @abulafia, quiero llenar el diccionario con un bucle, preguntando al usuario todas las conexiones que tenga el vértice principal, con los demás vértices, que el usuario solo llene las distancias que hay entre las conexiones, y si no hay dicha conexión que lo rellene con 0, para así poner una condición en la cual si es 0, no lo tome en cuenta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En python los diccionarios se van creando dinámicamente cuando asignas un valor a una de sus claves. Típicamente se empieza creando un diccionario vacío como `vertices = {}` y luego cuando asignas algo a `vertices["a"]` ese elemento es creado y el valor que le hayas asignado queda asociado con él.

El problema en tu caso es que los valores que tienes que asignar son a su vez diccionarios, por lo que para crear una estructura como la que muestras son necesarios dos bucles anidados.

Por ejemplo:

```
nodos = "abcdef"

vertices = {}

for origen in nodos:
  vertices[origen] = {}
  for destino in nodos:
    if origen == destino:
       continue # Este caso nos lo saltamos
    distancia = input("Distancia {}--{}? ".format(origen, destino))
    distancia = int(distancia)
    if distancia != 0:
       vertices[origen][destino] = distancia
```

**Nota**. Observa que el usuario podría perfectamente meter un grafo en el que la distancia a--b sea diferente de la distancia b--a, supongo que eso estará permitido. Observa también que si lo que el usuario mete no es un número, la línea `int(distancia)` romperá.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, me confunde mucho python ya que no es necesario inicializar variables, y los for tienen muchas mas formas de usarlos que en c++, o más formas de las que yo conocía.

Comment: @May395 Al contrario! Los bucles `for` en python tienen una sola forma, pero es tan potente que parecen muchas. Siempre es igual: `for variable in iterable`. Y lo que ocurre es que en cada iteración, el `iterable` devuelve un valor y ese se guarda en `variable`. La gracia es que el iterable puede ser una lista, una cadena, un fichero, un objetp `range()`, una función generadora ... y el valor retornado (que va a `variable`) puede ser cualquier tipo (incluso un tipo diferente en cada iteración)

Comment: Si, porque yo solo los había usado con int o con char como parámetro, pero ahora veo que tengo que investigar más sobre Python, porque usarlos con cadenas u objetos resulta ser muy útil.